Overleaf Compilation Problem with Package natbib Warning Error
I have spent days of trying to solve these problem but I failed. So I decide to ask for help from you guys. I am writing on Overleaf and using the model2-names.bst to generate my bibliography. However, it says that my citation is undefined.

\section{Introduction}
\label{introduction} 
a 

\citep{zhang2019modelling,xiao2018restrain,liu2018equilibrium,zhang2020sharing}, 
2 \citep{kaspi2014parking,liu2014expirable, chen2015parking} 
as \citep{zou2015mechanism,shao2016simple,boyles2015parking,liu2016managing}. 
ts \citep{mamandi2015game}, 
asing \citep{gindullina2021multi}, 
factors og \citep{fulman2020modeling}, 
determice \citep{lin2018dynamic}, 
optimin \citep{padma2020optimization}, 
and ms \citep{guo2013modeling}. 
F \citep{yan2022attitudes}, 
ps \citep{xu2016private, cheng2023novel,zhang2020parking}, 
rs \citep{kong2018iot,chou2018optimal,jiang2021matching}, 
ps \citep{ding2018research}, and 
mgn \citep{liu2022exploration,lai2021market}. 
Fng \citep{hu2015shared}, analing \citep{yan2020investigating}, 
ans \citep{tan2019sequential}.

\bibliographystyle{model2-names} % plainnat or try abbrvnat or unsrtnat
\bibliography{cas-refs} % refers to example.bib
%\printbibliography

\end{document}

After recompiling, the results are:

Interestingly, some references are shown but some are not.
I don't know why because all of them are downloaded in the bibtex version from google scholar. I appreciate your help!

Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to clear up a potentially simple issue: Have you verified that that the file cas-refs.bib contains the entries with keys zhang2019modelling, xiao2018restrain, zhang2020sharing, etc and that these entries are syntactically correct?

Welcome! Please copy-paste errors and other messages as text. Images cannot be indexed or searched and are useless to people who depend on screen-reading software.

The code you show doesn't include yu2022electric. Do you use it somewhere else? Or do the references you show use it? Are the missing references at the end of your .bib file? What is in the BibTeX log? Can you provide a minimal working example we can use to reproduce the problem?
